# NetSuite ERP: Write a date formulat in a mass update field

Tags: netsuite, erp

I am trying to use the mass updated feature in NetSuite to mass update a date field daily with the current date. There is a formula field for the date field, but I do not know what formula to write to return the current date when the massupdate is exectued.

Could someone help me please?

Many thanks

Ross

Answer (score 0):

```
{today}
```

will give you the current date.